# Cas with Liferay and Nuxeo

Tags: liferay, cas, nuxeo

I have integrated CAS with liferay and nuxeo.CAS is running in liferay tomcat server.
Now my issue is its expecting login again in one application even if I logged in into another application.

But its using the same ticket.Whether it should be configured somewhere?

Comment: Can you give more details about your problem ?

Comment: Also please indicate the versions, the documentations you followed and the configuration you did.